# "hold on" vs. "hold up" in informal English

Tags: slang, phrasal-verbs

To convey "wait a second" I always thought that "hold on" was the right phrasal verb. However I saw an American cartoon yesterday repeatedly using "hold up" to express the same. Is that correct or was it just part of the parody?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Both ‘[hold up’ and ‘hold on](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-hold-up-and-hold-on/)’*** can be used to ask someone to wait.

> “Hold up for a second.”
>
> “Hold on while I finish this.”
>
> - Technically speaking, the two do have different meanings. ‘Hold up’ is used to ask a person to stop or make a delay and ‘hold on’ is used to ask a person to wait. ***However, the two words are used interchangeably.***  There is not much difference between asking someone to wait and asking them to stop.

(www.differencebetween.net)